# WP Forms not displaying,becomming an fatal error

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, posts, menus, multisite

This is what i become after insterting a WPForm in Wordpress

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'There is no suitable CSPRNG installed on your system' in /var/customers/webs/harlac17/wp/wp-includes/random_compat/random.php:212 
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/customers/webs/harlac17/wp/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/libs/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php(2334): random_bytes(32) 
#1 /var/customers/webs/harlac17/wp/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/libs/sodium_compat/lib/php72compat.php(883): ParagonIE_Sodium_Compat::crypto_secretbox_keygen() 
#2 /var/customers/webs/harlac17/wp/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/src/Helpers/Crypto.php(37): sodium_crypto_secretbox_keygen() 
#3 /var/customers/webs/harlac17/wp/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/src/Forms/Token.php(59): WPForms\Helpers\Crypto::get_secret_key() 
#4 /var/customers/webs/harlac17/wp/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/src/Forms/Token.php(148): WPForms\Forms\Token->get() 
#5 [internal function]: WPForms\Forms\Token->add_token_to_form_atts(Array) 
#6 /var/customers/webs/harlac17/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): call_user_func_array( in /var/customers/webs/harlac17/wp/wp-includes/random_compat/random.php on line 212
```

Comment: It looks like WordPress is failing to find a [CSPRNG (cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) on your server. You'll need to talk to your hosting company about this. (If you *are* the hosting company, you'll need to look into PHP's [`random_bytes()`](https://www.php.net/random_bytes).)

Answer (score 0):

Googling for the Exception message

> There is no suitable CSPRNG installed on your system

Yielded a [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152618/there-is-no-suitable-csprng-installed-on-your-system) matching your issue.

When dealing with error messages, especially from plugins, it's usually helpful to [Google the message itself](https://www.google.com/search?q=There+is+no+suitable+CSPRNG+installed+on+your+system) - odds are someone else has already had the same problem, or the plugin maintainer may have addressed it in documentation or support forums.